# Npm resolving wrong version

Tags: npm, circleci

I have the following depndency in my package.json:

> "our-monitoring": "1.0.0",

and it works when I run `npm install`:

```
└─┬ our-monitoring@1.0.0
  └─┬ prom-client@10.0.2
    └─┬ tdigest@0.1.1
      └── bintrees@1.0.1
```

But when the project is ran in CircleCi, I get:

```
npm ERR! No compatible version found: our-monitoring@1.0.0
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget 0.1.0
```

Why? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might run into the same issue in the future:

Our package name was ambiguous - and our Nexus registry had a bug, so instead of always looking first at the private registry and then in the global, just served whichever was first.

So we sometimes received our package, and sometime the global npm package - but they had different version numbers, which is what created this specific error message.